# How to hold gun with leap motion hand

Tags: unity-game-engine, leap-motion

Newbie here, I'm developing game where I need to pick up gun and other objects. I'm using leap motion hands. How to pick up OR Connect gun with Leap Motion so that gun (or other) object move with hand motion.

P.S. I searched but failed to find any material across Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the limitations of the Leap Motion imposed by [physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics), this is almost certainly going to be impossible.

This is due to the location of the Leap Motion's IR camera and what it can (and more importantly, what it cannot) see. When your hand is in a fist, your fingers block the camera from being able to detect the position of most of your fingers, making any sort of typical gun-holding position impossible to detect. Note that this may change based on the location of your sensor bar (which you did not include in your question and I have limited experience with other mountings, but I can't think of any mounting where the Leap Motion would have the necessary unobstructed view).

There was a project I worked on where I tried to use that same kind of pose and a "trigger pull" motion to activate an effect inside the Unity application. However, due to the location of the sensor bar (on the desk) this was virtually impossible and we had to reconfigure for a horizontal hand position (location relative to sensor was movement, hand in a fist was "fire" and would not reset and allow a second fire until hand was in an open palm gesture).

Comment: Okay, If I change my question From "Gun" to "Sword" Where I only need to move hand to cut some object (may be Fruits - Fruit Ninja). Then How to Do that?.

Comment: Same problem applies, really. Best I can think of is that a) you'd be able to detect a closed fist and then b) use the wrist location to control your GameObject. Odds are it wouldn't look pretty or be as flexible as you want.